# How to update response xml using groovy and print it

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am completely new to Groovy and SOAPUI.

Scenario : Compare two xml response.(Both belong to different project)

Method Tried : capture the response and write the response to a file, compare both the files.

Issue faced : Timestamp mismatch as both request are run at different times

Due to the above issue I tried to get the Node value of time stamp and change it to * for both the responses. 
But I am unable to write the changed response value.

Groovy script :

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ); 
log.info( groovyUtils.projectPath ); 
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "loginRequest#Response" ) 
holder.setNodeValue( "//ns3:loginUserResponse[1]/ns3:loginUserResponse/userModel/auditModel/timestamp", "1" );
```

Initially `def holder` holds the response xml, but after getting the xml in holder, I am updating the node value. I am not sure how to proceed further. I need to write the updated xml to a file.

Comment: What is the error that you see? Stacktrace please?

Comment: You did not define namespaces in the your XPath! Try `holder.setNodeValue( "//*:loginUserResponse[1]/*:loginUserResponse/*:userModel/*:auditModel/*:timestamp", "1" )`.

Comment: use //*:elementName convention  for the xpath  and then use the groovy code  "holder.updateProperty()" and then write it to a file

Comment: @Rao I do not see any error, I am not sure how to proceed further after getting the XML into the holder

Comment: I understand that, and provided an answer using a random xml since you did not have any xml in the question. Please try it.

Comment: In my case I am getting the XML from the response in holder object. So If I need to use your code I need to convert it into string and check right ?

Comment: @RageshKr, updated my answer covering what you needed to change for dynamic response instead of fixed one, find the details in comments. All you need to do is remove the fixed xml statement and uncomment the currently commented line and replace value for your test step name in place of `TEST_STEP_NAME`. Hope that useful/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample groovy script which uses an arbitrary xml and updates an element value based on certain condition. Then it writes back the updated data to a file as requested. Please follow the in-line comments of the script.

And I believe that this will help your understanding and you will be able to apply it to your actual xml.

**What this script actually does?**
This xml has incorrect value for `madeBy` when car name is `i30`. And like to update xml with `Hyundai` and write it to the specified file.

```groovy
/**
* below is the groovy script which read and parses xml
* and updates its value and then writes back to file
**/
import groovy.xml.*
//Sample xml string
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cars>
  <car>
    <name>Jetta</name>
    <madeBy>Volkswagen</madeBy>
  </car>
  <car>
    <name>Polo GT</name>
    <madeBy>Volkswagen</madeBy>
  </car>
  <car>
    <name>i30</name>
    <madeBy>Typo</madeBy>
  </car>
</cars>'''
//if you want to pass the dynamic response instead of above fixed xml, then
//use below statements by uncommenting below one and replace value for TEST_STEP_NAME and
//comment above xml statement
/**
def xml = context.expand('${TEST_STEP_NAME#Response}')
**/
//parse the xml string and create object
def cars = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
//find the car whose name is i30 and update its madeBy element value to Hyundai
cars.'**'.find { if (it.name == 'i30') it.madeBy = 'Hyundai'}
//print changed cars object
println XmlUtil.serialize(cars)
//Serializes and Writes cars object into given file
new File('c:/Temp/test1.xml').write(XmlUtil.serialize(cars))
```

If you open your xml file, the **output** should be as shown below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
  <car>
    <name>Jetta</name>
    <madeBy>Volkswagen</madeBy>
  </car>
  <car>
    <name>Polo GT</name>
    <madeBy>Volkswagen</madeBy>
  </car>
  <car>
    <name>i30</name>         
    <madeBy>Hyundai</madeBy>
  </car>
</cars>
```

You may also find [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/10/groovy-goodness-creating-xml-with.html) example useful which illustrates to create a new xml altogether.